# POST working with Postman but not via fetch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, fetch

The post request to the Django Rest API framework works via Postman when the appropriate parameters are filled in the 'body' section. But the same does not work with the following JavaScript code:

```
var data = {emp_id:50,emp_name:'test',password:'pass123'};   
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/',{
    method:"POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    mode:"no-cors",
     headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
    })
    .then(response => response.json());
```

The following is the def that handles the POST request in the views.py of the REST-API:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
def signup(request):
    serializer = employeeSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I'm new to this, can anyone tell me why the JavaScript code won't work?

EDIT:
The error which the browser console shows is:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Comment: what is the result? what error message do you see in Developer Tools if any?

Comment: do you not need another `.then` call in order to do something with the JSON response?

Comment: _“can anyone tell me why the JavaScript code won't work?”_ - your browser console most likely can, so go check there. It is likely to point out that you have a CORS issues, so go read up on that keyword then if it is news to you.

Comment: @skyboyer, there is an error message: 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that by using `no-cors` mode you constrain yourself to using [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), which in turn cannot have content-type other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`. In fact, if you look at the headers sent by the browser with your request, you'll see that the content type changes from `application/json` to `text/plain` - hence the error.

To fix your issue: remove `no-cors` mode and add cors headers to responses in your django app. You can use [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) for that.

Also, you have no issues with postman because it does not care about [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution here : https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/#generating-code-snippets-in-postman

with postman you can see the code of headers sent on the request on many languages (Node Axios, javascript fetch ...), then just copy paste the headers and all the data sent by postman to your app

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30635442)

Comment: beautiful comment, this fixed it for me!

Answer (score 3):

Try change headers to

```
headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
}
```

The accept header is used by to determine what format to sent the data back to the client in the response, guess it might be needed